# Git First Push to Remote Repository Failed

Tags: git

I created a new Visual Studio 2015 Solution and put the source files in a local repository on my laptop (Windows 7). On my Mac Fileserver I created a new bare repository (`git init --bare --shared filename.git`).

Back on my laptop I connected to my Mac Fileserver using a VPN connection and mounted the mapped drive where the remote repository is.

I configure the remote repository in Visual Studio (`file:///Z:\path to remote repository`).

I try to push the committed files but I get the following error:

> Error encountered while publishing branch to the remote repository:
>   Failed to rename lockfile to 'Z:/path to .git
>   file/objects/pack/pack-6e7d6ac4bae59d61509d77b0ab11a393625e8859.idx':
>   Access is denied.

I opened the local repository in Git Gui and tried again but the same error.

I have followed the same process on a simpler Visual Studio project with success, perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Can anyone offer any suggestions please?